# What is the #<number> after column name in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I don't have any specific purpose to understand the meaning of the weird names, I am just interested in it.

Here is a simple code for the same.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], 'c1: string, c2: string')
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 'p'], ['c', 'q']], 'c1: string, c3: string')
df1.join(df2, df1.c1 == df2.c1).explain()
```

It outputs

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- SortMergeJoin [c1#0], [c1#4], Inner
   :- Sort [c1#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#0, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=191]
   :     +- Filter isnotnull(c1#0)
   :        +- Scan ExistingRDD[c1#0,c2#1]
   +- Sort [c1#4 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#4, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=192]
         +- Filter isnotnull(c1#4)
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[c1#4,c3#5]
```

The column names are followed by numbers like `c1#0` and `c2#1`. What are these numbers? One thing I can understand is that they help in differentiating the columns with same name in different dataframes like `c1#0` and `c1#4`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This will be used in `import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference` class for every column in `DataFrame`

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you tell what is the meaning of named expression? And is the attribute reference built called for each query?

Comment: Also, can I access this exprId from the column itself? If there is a column named c1, can I do something like c1.<something>.exprId?

Comment: you should ask these as separate questions if you want a detailed reply, but for this kind of thing look at the source, namedexpressions are exactly as you'd imagine, an expression with a name.  You _can_ access the id - but what do you even need this for?

Comment: Hey @Chris, I thought these were small things. Will take care of it next time. By the way, can you tell me how to access the id? I am just curious about it, nothing specific. Maybe it will help me debug something else.

Comment: Hey @Dhruv, `id` is column .. you can access as part of `select` statement. for more details on this.. please import git code into ide & check the class which I have mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: Hey, @s.polam I was asking to extract `exprId` from the column. Can you tell me how to do so?

Comment: as per above, ask a separate question, in short it's by going through the query plan.  You are best of investigating this by using a scala ide, it's all on the jvm and written in scala